# How to connect to a mysql database that is on a virtual machine

Tags: java, mysql, linux, windows

I have a problem while trying to connect to my database.
I have on my windows pc a java app and in a Linux virtual Machine (Ubuntu) a mysql Database. Is there anything i need to configure in order to connect my java app to my mysql database?

Thanks

Comment: It depends on the VM software. You probably need to enable a port forward, and you still have to enable remote host support for mysql.

Comment: Im using vmware. I have set the bind-address to 0.0.0.0...

Comment: And you'll probably want to make sure that port 3306 not being blocked by the Ubuntu firewall.

Answer (score 0):

First make sure that you are able to connect to the database server from your windows machine(cmd). If you not able to, give the necessary permission for the user in your mysql server.

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13752424/how-to-connect-from-windows-command-prompt-to-mysql-command-line
```

Answer (score 0):

What was happening was that when you install postgres in linux, you have to set a password, i mean it hasnt came with a pass