# insert table from file in phpmyadmin Cloud9

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, cloud9-ide

When I try to insert a CSV file gives me the error "No data was received to import. Either no file name was submitted, or the file size exceeded the maximum size permitted by your PHP configuration"
I tried to change the size of the data in the php.ini, but it did not help. :(

Please, help!

Comment: I think this is related to phpMyAdmin limits. Can you try uploading your file by dragging & dropping the CSV into your workspace and then trying `mysqldump`. Alternatively you can adjust the phpMyAdmin limits.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using linux OS please try in terminal mode.

```
cd /your file path

mysql -u root -p123456

use database name

source filename
```

I think this will help you to solve this.

Comment: No, I use the cloud9(my system is windows)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13752424/how-to-connect-from-windows-command-prompt-to-mysql-command-line  please check this and this will help you..