# How to create user in MySQL and login

Tags: mysql

I am very new to MySQL and I am trying to install it and set up MySQL so I can practice and learn it for an Independent Study at school. I am following this video "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O4xXzTIcnDE" on how to install MySQL. If someone knows of a better video to follow for installing MySQL please link it. I am using a Windows 7 Samsung laptop 64 bit.

I am stuck on the user and password part. I followed the video and tried to create a user and password but I get an error when I try to log in with "C:\mysql\bin>mysql -u root -p".

Here is the exact code from cmd. Look at the last 2 lines for the error. I used this line to create a user and gave it a password: "mysql> update mysql.user set password = password('password') where user = 'root';"

I set password = to password so it would be easy to remember.

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Windows\system32>mysqld --install
Service successfully installed.

C:\Windows\system32>mysql -u root
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061)

C:\Windows\system32>sc delete MySQL
[SC] DeleteService SUCCESS

C:\Windows\system32>cd\mysql\bin

C:\mysql\bin>mysqld --install
The service already exists!
The current server installed: "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\mysqld" MySQL

C:\mysql\bin>mysqld --remove
The service doesn't exist!

C:\mysql\bin>mysqld --install
Service successfully installed.

C:\mysql\bin>mysql -u root -p
Enter password:
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 1
Server version: 5.6.24 MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2015, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql> use mysql;
Database changed
mysql> update mysql.user set password = password('password') where user = 'root'
-> update mysql.user set password = password('password') where user = 'root';
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corre
sponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'update mysql.us
er set password = password('password') where user = 'root'' at line 2
mysql>
mysql> update mysql.user set password = password('password') where user = 'root';
Query OK, 3 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 3  Changed: 3  Warnings: 0

mysql> select user, host from user;
+------+-----------+
| user | host      |
+------+-----------+
| root | 127.0.0.1 |
| root | ::1       |
|      | localhost |
| root | localhost |
+------+-----------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select user, host from user where user = '';
+------+-----------+
| user | host      |
+------+-----------+
|      | localhost |
+------+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> delete from user where user = '';
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> quit
Bye

C:\mysql\bin>mysql -u root -p
Enter password: ********
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

C:\mysql\bin>mysql -u root -p
Enter password: ********
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

C:\mysql\bin>
```

Comment: google it. lots of tutorials are available ->  https://www.google.com.bd/?gws_rd=cr,ssl&ei=iBViVamcF4OSuAT6kIHwBA#q=how+to+setup+mysql+database+on+windows

Comment: U should try portable version of Wamp : Uniform Server.

Answer (score -1):

Try to **google** it!

[How to setup mysql database](https://www.google.com.bd/?gws_rd=cr,ssl&ei=iBViVamcF4OSuAT6kIHwBA#q=how%20to%20setup%20mysql%20database%20on%20windows)

I like this tutorial. Try this tutorial **Step by Step**:

[Installing mysql step by step](http://ushastry.blogspot.com/2009/06/installing-mysql-on-windows.html)

**Edited:**
Use this command to log in as admin:

```
C:\MYSQL\Bin>mysql -u root -p admin
```

link:
[How to connect from windows command prompt to mysql command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13752424/how-to-connect-from-windows-command-prompt-to-mysql-command-line)