# How can I access mysql/phpmyadmin locally without xampp/wamp?

Tags: php, mysql, database, phpmyadmin, localhost

I use `php -S localhost:8000` command in git-bash in the path of project for running php.
I need to have a look of my tables. In phpmyadmin for example or any other ways.
Please help me. How can I do that?
thanks

Comment: PHP doesn't come bundled with a database, that's why XAMPP/LAMP is a nice bundle for beginners (it has Apache and a database in its stack). If you only use PHP individually, you need to install a MySQL/MariaDB server instance separately

Comment: Why not use a docker-based setup (like ddev)? This helps you bundling all depending services in the correct versions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access MySQL through Client CLI ([command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13752424/how-to-connect-from-windows-command-prompt-to-mysql-command-line)), or any MySQL client ([datagrip (not free)](https://www.jetbrains.com/fr-fr/datagrip/), [dbforge](https://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/), [heidisql](https://www.heidisql.com/))... PHPMyAdmin is just a web MySQL Client.

If you want to access your database through PHPMyAdmin you need a web server. You can run the command you mentionned `php -S localhost:8000` inside the PHPMyAdmin source directory (source location depend on your installation) to run the PHP web server.